# Help with Variational Formulation

Tags: finite-element

Am solving a system of pdes in Fenics and need to write the variational form. Everything looks good expect a term like the following
$$ \nabla \xi\nabla \cdot U $$
$\mathbf{U} = (U,V) $ is a vector function and $\xi$ is a scalar function in 2d.
So I tried the following. Multiply by a vector function $p$ and integrate by part I arrived at the following, assuming that $p$ vanishes on the boundary.
$$-\int (\xi \nabla \cdot \mathbf{U})\cdot\nabla p\space dx .$$
But this doesn't look right. Can anybody please help with this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand how did you apply the divergence theorem for the first term in 2, can you explain this more?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying term by a vector test function $\mathbf{p}$ and integrating over the domain $\Omega$ gives:

$$\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot \mathbf{U}\nabla\xi\cdot\mathbf{p}d\Omega\qquad (1)$$

To start with you can write:

$$ \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{p}\xi) = \xi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{p}\cdot\nabla\xi$$

Which gives:

$$ \mathbf{p}\cdot\nabla\xi = \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{p}\xi) - \xi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p}$$

Plugging this into (1):

$$\int_\Omega \nabla\cdot \mathbf{U}\left(\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{p}\xi) - \xi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p}\right) d\Omega\qquad (2)$$

Recall the Divergence theorem:

$$ \int_\Omega \nabla\cdot \mathbf{F} d\Omega = \int_\Gamma \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}d\Gamma$$
where $\Gamma$ is the boundary of $\Omega$.

Applying this to the first term in (2) gives the final form:

$$\int_\Gamma \nabla\cdot \mathbf{U} \xi(\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{n})d\Gamma - \int_\Omega \nabla\cdot \mathbf{U} \xi\nabla\cdot\mathbf{p}d\Omega$$

The first term is 0 if $\mathbf{p}$ vanishes on the boundary.

Comment: No problem. Hope all the steps are clear. I think this way is slightly longer but also a little bit more clear than just using integration by parts.